# 新たに meaning in a sentence

Tags: meaning

> **タブレットは生徒に1台ずつ与えられており、教室後方には高速充電可能な機器も新たに備え付けられた。**

I have a little bit doubt about the proper interpretation of the sentence.

**機器も新たに** means **a new device**, but **新たに備え付けられた** means **newly installed**/**installed recently** (I personally think it might be the proper one).

One other thing, **高速充電可能な機器も** in my interpretation is **a fast charging device**, so **可能な** can be omitted if I translated the sentence in English.

Thank you for your kind guidance in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

機器も新たに does not mean "a new device". 新たに is an adverbial expression that modifies the following verb (備え付けられた). The sentence says "～ was **newly** installed".

高速充電可能な機器 is "fast-charge**able** devices" if you want to translate it literally. I think this probably refers to chargers in this context, but it can possibly refer to tablets that can be charged quickly, too. 高速充電機器 also makes sense and it would only refer to quick chargers.

Comment: As I read through the preceding sentences and the next sentences, I also think it might be a charger installed on the wall behind the classroom. So I'm guessing the literal translation is "a device that can charge it (the tablet computer) quickly". That's why I thought it's possible to omit 可能な, if I put it simple as a fast charging devices (the popular term). Thank you for your kind explanation, I have a better understanding on how to read the sentence properly.